# Play a sound when ListView item is pressed

Tags: android, audio, android-listview, onclick, playback

I'm just starting out in android development so excuse me, also I've searched yet nothing I found is beginner friendly.

What I'm trying to achieve is when an item on my listview is pressed, a short sound clip is played, the clips are probably just 2 seconds long. Here is my code so far, I've followed  a tutorial to create the list view.

So to be clear, it will be  a list of names and when a name is clicked the sound will be played.

NamesList.java

```
    package me.creativebla.names;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class NamesList extends ListActivity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // storing string resources into Array
        String[] names = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.names);

        // Binding resources Array to ListAdapter
        this.setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.activity_names_list, R.id.label, names));

        ListView lv = getListView();



            }
        };
```

And the list data is found in list_data.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<resources>
         <string-array name="names">
            <item>Name 1</item>
            <item>Name 2</item>
            <item>Name 3</item>
         </string-array> 
</resources>
```

I'd really appreciate if someone could help me, step by step and tell me what needs doing. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have two sound files named "rock_sound" and "disco_sound" in the **res/raw** folder, the listview listen for the click events and play the sound based on the position(name in list) clicked:

```
package me.creativebla.names;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class NamesList extends ListActivity {
    private SoundPool soundPool;
    private int soundID1;
    private int soundID2;
    private boolean soundLoaded;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.name_of_layout);
     // Set hardware buttons to control music
        this.setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        // storing string resources into Array
        String[] names = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.names);

        // Binding resources Array to ListAdapter
        this.setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.activity_names_list, R.id.label, names));

        ListView lv = getListView();

            // load the sound here
        soundPool = new SoundPool(10, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0); //first parameter restricts the number of sound effects can be played concurrently
        soundPool.setOnLoadCompleteListener(new OnLoadCompleteListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLoadComplete(SoundPool soundPool, int sampleId, int status) {
                if (sampleId == R.raw.rock_sound) {
                    soundLoaded = true;
                }
            }
        });
    soundID1 = soundPool.load(this, R.raw.rock_sound, 1);
    soundID2 = soundPool.load(this, R.raw.disco_sound, 1);

        }
    };

lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position,
                    long arg3) {
                //play sound based on item name clicked
                  switch(position){
                   case 0:
                   playSound(soundID1, 1.0f);
                      break;
                   case 1:
                   playSound(soundID2, 0.5f);
                      break;
                 }

            }
        });
```

//method to play sound. volume is a float value with range 0.0(lowest) 1.0(maximum)

```
 private void playSound(int soundId, float volume) {
         if (soundLoaded)
        soundPool.play(soundId, volume, volume, 1, 0, 1f);
    }
}
```